# change browser behavior for web page with invalid certificate

Tags: windows, web, internet-explorer, iis, https

When a user tries to browse webpage having an invalid certificate(expired,self-signed, untrusted root, etc..),
browser warns the user about the security issue with page give option to proceed or return back.
Is it possible the change the page(default) that's being displayed here? how to get into the chain of event that gets trigger after the browser evaluates certificate validity?

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks,

Comment: Impossible to control that on server side. That page is part of the browser settings, so varied by vendors (IE/Chrome/Edge/Firefox each has a unique page). No matter what kind of network you are targeting, internet or intranet, you should use a valid certificate from public or internal CA.

Comment: Yeah, every browser has a different page. Is it possible to pass on the custom page for any browser!

Comment: Browsers show that kind of page during initial SSL/TLS handshakes, so no traffic lands on your web server yet. That's why you cannot pass your custom page, and I said it is impossible on the server side. Try to get a valid server certificate please, as today there are several options including free ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to achieve that feature on the server-side. It is a part of the client-side's browser implementation on validating the server-side’s certificate.
As you know, the Https connection based on the SSL/TLS version between the client-side and the server-side. establishing the TLS connection requires a handshake between the server-side and the client-side.
[image]
The client and server will provide the available TLS version during the process, including the supported certificate encryption algorithm and certificate public key. If the process fails, we cannot program the webpage displayed on the client-side since the `TLS` connection has not been established yet.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, its more clear now. 
All this is for browser traffic to go directly to a remote server. If it goes through a proxy server and proxy query remote certificate and decide to pass its custom error page to browse. is this possible!

Comment: I am afraid of not. It is a part of browser implementation.
this web page perform the process of validating the server's certificate. The validation process is completed by the client browser. It is a built-in feature of the browser. Besides, the validation result could be modified by changing the certificate trust chain, such as adding the remote server certificate to local Trusted Root Certification Authorities.